# Add post meta based on another post meta value before publish post

Tags: post-meta, save-post

I want to add a meta value to my post , which will be based on another meta value , before publish post .  This is what I have tried

```
add_action('save_post_my_custom_post', 'add_custom_field_automatically' );
function add_custom_field_automatically($post_ID) { 

    $new_meta_value = get_post_meta($post_ID,'_my_meta_key',TRUE).'to ' .' something new';

    add_post_meta($post_ID, '_my_new_meta_key', $new_meta_value, true);
}
```

But it doesn't work . The hook fired properly , it saves only "to something new" , but what I expect the value should be "my meta value to something new"

Comment: Which hook it is `save_my_custom_post` ?

Comment: here  my_custom_post    is the name of my custom post type .  Technically it is the 'save_post' hook .

Comment: Can you elaborate by "doesn't work" - have you checked that the hook is definitely firing ([use error logging to debug](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/using-the-wordpress-debug-log))? Is it saving data but not what you expected?

Comment: Oh! then it should be `save_post_my_custom_post` because hook name is `save_post_{post_type}`

Comment: @Sumit sorry , my bad , I have edited my question , it still doesn't work .

Comment: Then maybe should try what TheDeadMedic said because there no error which I can tell you in your code except `add_post_meta` with `true` as last argument. Which mean data will be not added if already exist.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic , The hook fired , it is saving data but not as expected . 

It saves only "to something new" , but what I expect the value should be "my meta value to something new"

Comment: Then that must mean there is no data for `_my_meta_key` at the time your code runs.

Comment: I have found the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is using `added_post_meta` and `updated_post_meta` hook .

Here is the working code .

```
add_action( 'added_post_meta', 'add_custom_field_automatically', 10, 4 );
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'add_custom_field_automatically', 10, 4 );
function add_custom_field_automatically( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )
{
    if ( '_my_meta_key' == $meta_key ) {

        add_post_meta($post_id, '_my_new_meta_key', $meta_value.'to something new', true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `global $post` at the top of the page just before the function start

```
global $post;
```